# Run command after N failed local login attempts

Tags: linux, security

Any good ways of running a linux command (shell script for instance) when N failed local login attempts happens?

Maybe using pam_tally?

Answer (score 2):

I would use fail2ban to do it.  It's already setup to watch log files and act on them if it sees X authentication failures.

The default patterns probably won't match local login failures, but you can easily add your own.  And you can setup custom actions to take instead of the default blocking an IP in iptables.

Answer (score 2):

[Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a tool that can do that for you.